# SwiftUI: Label randomly cropped

Tags: swiftui

I have a litte SwiftUI example with a strange behaviour. It displays a Button and an optional Text. With a button tap the text is updated.

Strange effect: Sometimes the button label gets cropped.

Of course I could assign some frame size for the button as a work around. But is this really necessary?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var tapCount = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.tapCount+=1
            }) {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "hand.point.right").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                    Text("Tap Me")
                    Image(systemName: "hand.point.left").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                }
            }

            if self.tapCount > 0{
                Text("You tapped \(tapCount) times")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, frame is not needed, it is enough to point that text is fixed size, as below

```
Text("Tap Me")
  .fixedSize()
```

Comment: But why is this needed? Is it a bug? Because otherwise I have to put it on each Text element that eventually might break.

Comment: @netshark1000, no, I don't think it is needed in *all* cases, but in your case it might happen due to overlapped redrawing events (note, if tap slowly then all is ok, and if no symbol images then also ok), which affect relayout engine.

Comment: @netshark1000 if you don't like .fixedSize(), use .scaledToFill() with the same effect